# Deploying Azure Container Instance in differents RGs

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances

I need to deploy Azure container instance in differents Resource Groups.

In one Resource Group I allocate only the ACI and on another Resource Group I allocate the Vnet

Is this possible? I think that is not possible by design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.

You can create an azure container instance in a virtual network that is in a different resource group from the container instance resource group.

Suppose you have created a vNet `myvnet` and subnet `aci-subnet` in the RG `myvnetRG` for your ACI. Then you could use the following [deployment examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet#deployment-examples).

```
VnetId=$(az network Vnet show -g myvnetRG -n myvnet --query 'id' -o tsv)
az container create -n appcontainer -g containerRG --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld --vnet $VnetId --subnet aci-subnet
```

You can also deploy a container group to an existing virtual network by [using a YAML file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet#deploy-to-existing-virtual-network---yaml), then specify several additional properties like network profile and ID in the YAML.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by design, but why would you want to do that? It is not a recommended design thought.

If your resource groups in the different regions, you could configure a Vnet-to-Vnet connection. For your reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal

Comment: Can you help me to create an ACI with a vnet on a different RG? CAn you give me the powershell for this?

Comment: They arent in different regions, only in different resource groups